# How to create a data file in R program

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I want to show sum of cluster in different districts on a map in R. 
The data file i have imported in R studio contains total of 11 clusters appearing multiple times in a district. Below is the data example:

```
District       cluster
Rawalpindi     A
Lahore         A
Multan         A
Rawalpindi     A
Rawalpindi     A
Lahore         A
Lahore         A
Lahore         A
Multan         A
Rawalpindi     B
Rawalpindi     B
Rawalpindi     B
Rawalpindi     A
Lahore         B
Lahore         B
Multan         B
Multan         B
Rawalpindi     C
Rawalpindi     C
Rawalpindi     C
Rawalpindi     C
Rawalpindi     C
Rawalpindi     C
Lahore         C
```

I want to crate a separate file to work with to create map, which will contain only the sum of clusters according to districts.
Your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: do take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and learn how to create a reproducible example. You need to show what have you tried so far and where are you stuck at. StackOverflow is NOT a code-vending website.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have downloaded the map in R and now want to show my data i.e number of cluster in a district as a circle. The size of the circle will show the number/times that cluster appeared in specific district

Answer (score 1):

```
#Sample dataframe 
df <- data.frame(District=c('Rawalpindi','Lahore','Multan', 'Rawalpindi', 'Lahore'), cluster=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'))
fun <- function(col){ length(unique(col)) }
aggregate(cluster ~ District, df, fun)
```

Comment: @nayab Is this the solution you were looking for?

Comment: thank you for your help. i am having "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'district' not found" this error

Comment: although the district column name in my file is exactly the same